# PCL and ROS Indigo: No such file or directory

Tags: pcl, catkin, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to compile a package that uses ROS Indigo and PCL trunk. This is the error:

```
/home/andreas/baxter_ws/src/object_grasping/src/lccp_clustering.cpp:58:48: fatal error: pcl/segmentation/lccp_segmentation.h: No such file or directory
#include <pcl/segmentation/lccp_segmentation.h>
```

The header lccp_segmentation.h is in: */usr/local/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/segmentation/*

The CMakeLists.txt has this: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#PCL and the package.xml has this: https://github.com/ros-perception/pcl_conversions/commit/a868e1a16e442c135f66a9738619d290bc4ee896

Why does the package not find the header?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213719/pcl-and-ros-indigo:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2015-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2015-07-14**:
I solved this by adding find_package(PCL 1.8 REQUIRED) and link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}) to CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's probably not getting the correct include path, since `pcl-1.8` is in the path of the header you need. You'll need to ensure that the package you're building is finding pcl 1.8 rather than 1.7 or some other version and then ensure that it's passing the correct include paths to the building of your library/executable. It might be useful to run with `VERBOSE=1` to see what arguments are being passed to `c++`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1